# Weird behavior of Set.equals

Tags: java, hibernate, set, equals, hashcode

I am encountering a weird behavior when trying to see if two sets are equal. I have overridden the equals and hashcode:

```
public class Metric {


    private String id;

    private Sensor sensor;

    private String metricName;

    private String metricDescription;

    //getters, setters, toString()...

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((metricDescription == null) ? 0 : metricDescription.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((metricName == null) ? 0 : metricName.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Metric other = (Metric) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        if (metricDescription == null) {
            if (other.metricDescription != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!metricDescription.equals(other.metricDescription))
            return false;
        if (metricName == null) {
            if (other.metricName != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!metricName.equals(other.metricName))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

I have intentionally left the Sensor information out of the hashCode and equals, but in both so it should not make a difference.

Now, consider the following code:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Transaction tx = null;

    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(datasource);
        session.save(sensorType);
        session.save(sensor);
        session.save(metric1);
        session.save(metric2);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx != null)
            tx.rollback();
        throw e;
    } finally {
        if (session.isOpen())
            session.close();
    }

    try {
        session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        sameSensor = (Sensor) session.get(Sensor.class, new String(sensor.getId()));
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx != null)
            tx.rollback();
        throw e;
    } finally {
        if (session.isOpen())
            session.close();
    }

    // simply retrieve the metrics
    Set<Metric> sensorMetrics = sensor.getMetrics();
    Set<Metric> sameSensorMetrics = sameSensor.getMetrics();
    System.out.println("SENSOR METRIC");
    for(Metric m : sensorMetrics) {
        System.out.println(m.getMetricName() + ":" + m.hashCode());
        System.out.println(sameSensorMetrics.contains(m));
    }
    System.out.println("SAME SENSOR METRIC");
    for(Metric m : sameSensorMetrics) {
        System.out.println(m.getMetricName() + ":" + m.hashCode());
        System.out.println(sensorMetrics.contains(m));

    }
```

The two sets should be identical (and all the hascodes are), but I am getting the following result:

```
SENSOR METRIC
metric2name_addSensor_1393695505000:-1437647480
true
metric1name_addSensor_1393695505000:2040143911
true

SAME SENSOR METRIC
metric1name_addSensor_1393695505000:2040143911
false
metric2name_addSensor_1393695505000:-1437647480
false
```

Even though the metrics are the same (I have checked the equals on all the pairs, the results are correct) the metrics are contained in one set but not the other... I really can't explain this and would appreciate any help.

I have given code snippets that I believe are the important ones, if any more information is needed I will be more than happy to provide. Thanks.

**EDIT:**

1) The code where Sensor is initialized as dfb requested:

```
/*
 * Create all the sensor-related information to insert
 */

DataSource datasource = new DataSource();
datasource.setDatasourceName(
        createUniqueString("datasource","addSensor"));
datasource.setDatasourceDescription(
        createUniqueString("datasource","addSensor","description"));

SensorType sensorType = new SensorType();
sensorType.setSensorTypeName(
        createUniqueString("sensortype","addSensor"));
sensorType.setSensorTypeDescription(
        createUniqueString("sensortype","addSensor","description")); 

Sensor sensor = new Sensor();
sensor.setDatasource(datasource);
sensor.setSensorType(sensorType);
sensor.setSensorName(createUniqueString("sensorname","addSensor"));
sensor.setSensorDescription(createUniqueString("sensordesc","addSensor","description"));

Metric metric1 = new Metric();
metric1.setMetricDescription(
        createUniqueString("metric1name","addSensor","description"));
metric1.setMetricName(
        createUniqueString("metric1name","addSensor"));
metric1.setSensor(sensor);

Metric metric2 = new Metric();
metric2.setMetricDescription(
        createUniqueString("metric2name","addSensor","description"));
metric2.setMetricName(
        createUniqueString("metric2name","addSensor"));
metric2.setSensor(sensor);

sensor.addMetric(metric1);
sensor.addMetric(metric2);
```

And the Sensor constructor:

```
Sensor() {
    this.metrics = new HashSet<Metric>();
}
```

2) The weird behavior seems to be the Sensor instance that was saved, not the one that was loaded:

```
Set<Metric> sensorMetrics2 = sensor.getMetrics();
Set<Metric> sensorMetrics = sensor.getMetrics();
System.out.println(sensorMetrics2.equals(sensorMetrics));
System.out.println(sensorMetrics.equals(sensorMetrics));

Set<Metric> sameSensorMetrics2 = sameSensor.getMetrics();
Set<Metric> sameSensorMetrics = sameSensor.getMetrics();
System.out.println(sameSensorMetrics2.equals(sameSensorMetrics));
System.out.println(sameSensorMetrics.equals(sameSensorMetrics2));
```

The results:

```
false
false

true
true
```

Comment: @NiksTyagi can you please elaborate? From what I have read in the API for comparing sets you need to override the equals and hashcode.

Comment: ohh just a minute u r  comparing not sorting

Comment: That's really strange. Can you reproduce this behaviour in a code that perhaps doesn't include the hibernate related stuffs, so that we can test it?

Comment: I can try, but the Hibernate stuff is crucial, the entire class's purpose to be Hibernated :)

Comment: I suspect this might have something to do with the fact that you're saving `sensorMetrics` and the getting back `sameSensorMetrics` (e.g., the id field being populated by hibernate) messing with the equality test.  Can you show us where `sensor` is initialized and any related mapping code?

Comment: The reason for removing the hibernation code is to isolate the problem. Is it with your `Metric` class, or is it elsewhere? Your `equals` and `hashCode` methods look good to me, so I suspect you'll be unable to reproduce the problem with `Metric` alone.

Comment: I understand and I believe that you are right (from quick testing, doing some more). So perhaps this is a Hibernate specific problem... Still puzzling though :)

Answer (score 0):

Following construct is problematic with Hibernate, because hibernate tends to create proxies for entities because of need for lazy loading:

```
if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
  return false;
```

Proxy is subclass of Metrics and thats why code above does not work, but code likely does:

```
if (!(obj instanceof Metrics)) {
  return false;
}
```

More instructions about overriding equals and hashcode for entities can be found from [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch04.html#persistent-classes-equalshashcode). Also instanceof can bring surprises, as is told in [this](http://blog.xebia.com/2008/03/08/advanced-hibernate-proxy-pitfalls/) blog post.

Comment: My Fetching strategy is join, which means no lazy loading occurs.  Correct me if I'm wrong but getting the object with JOIN fetch should give me the Metric object that I am expecting. Also, while debugging I can see clearly that it fails on the set.equals... All the instances are of class Metric.